# Designing a custom view on android

Tags: android, user-interface

I'd like to create a custom view of "Player" for a card game.

1. Semi-transparent rectangle (this is my main problem, I don't know how i can do that).
2. Player's avatar in the middle of that rectangle.
3. The players card below (overlapping the rectangle).

Something like that:

[image]

Is that possible without drawing on canvas (only using xml and classes)?

Because i'd like to create one component and reuse it for different players.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a layout and mak a own drawable whick you kann bind with

`android:background="@drawable/custom_button_white"`

The drawable is defined like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#99999999"
        android:endColor="#99999999"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#99000000" />
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector
```

Whith the first two digits of the color you are able to adust the transparency

Comment: Hi, your code is great, but i can't get the transparent right, can you please point me on which color are you referring to? Thanks.

Comment: the first two digits of start and end color will let the shape appear more (00) or less(ff) transparent

Comment: Maybe i'm doing something wrong, but it just gives me different colors and not transparent, for example i tried startColor="#ff9999", endColor="#ff9999", it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: you have to use 8 digits, the first two for the transparency level and the other six for the color (as usual) if you write only 6 digits the amount of transparecy will be ff (nothing)